# Java 6 RegEx to match all characters NOT in Unicode's Letters and Marks categories

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I need to remove all non Letter and Mark (Unicode categories) characters from a string. Currently I'm splitting and subsequently joining a string like so:

```
text.split("[\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r]")
```

My RegEx is however... acutely inadequate. Please help.

**EDIT**
I think this will work:

```
text.split("[\\P{M}\\P{L}]")
```

Comment: I'm not a Java user in PCRE \X should match [all unicode characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]", "");
```

See more in http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: I change my answer. Although apparently already found the solution.

Comment: Unlike me, you got the closing braket right :-) I think this entitles you to some points.